# creating multiple zip files based on size

Tags: zip

I have 150GB of jpg's in around 30 folders. I am trying to import them into the media library of a CMS. The CMS will accept a bulk import of images in a zip file but there is a limit of 500MB on the size of the zip (and it won't accept multi-volume zips).

I need to go into each folder and zip the images into a small number of ~500MB zip files. I am using WinRAR but it doesn't seem to have the facility to do what I want.

Is there another product that will do what I want?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with WinRAR also. Please see this guide: [Create Multi-part Archives to Split Large Files for Emailing, Writing to CD [How To]](http://mintywhite.com/vista/create-multipart-archives-split-large-files-emailing-writing-cd/)

Comment: yes, but the CMS won't accept multi-part archives. It needs independent zip files.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read carefully. See this http://superuser.com/questions/168207/how-to-split-a-zip-file-across-independent-volumes

Comment: That was just what I needed [spinzip](http://skwire.dcmembers.com/wb/pages/software/spinzip.php) did just what I wanted.